# How to create an array of buttons on Borland C++ Builder and work with it?

Tags: c++builder

### Specific question

How to create an array of buttons on Borland C++ Builder and work with it?

I'm using Borland C++ Builder 6 and Borland Developer Studio 2006 (Turbo C++ 2006).

### Purpose

To work with a lot of buttons on a form just using a for loop with an index, for example, changing their caption, size and position.

I know if I have a button called `Button1` and inside a click event of this button if I create another button (through `TButton *Button2 = new TButton(Form1)`), I can assign `Button1` to `Button2` (`Button2 = Button1`) and them I can simply modify caption of `Button1` with `Button2->Caption`. So I would like to extend it assigning pointers of real components to elements of an array to them work with all of them with a `for` loop.

Well, if someone found an way to add all buttons as an array on a form, it's better :)

### Tries

Following tests were made putting respective code on TForm1::Button1Click(), an event of a button on a form:

- Test 1

  - Description: Creating an array directly
  - Code:

    ```
    TButton Buttons[3];
    ```
  - Result: Compile error:

    ```
    > [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(23): E2248 Cannot find default constructor
    > to initialize array element of type 'TButton'
    ```
  - Comments:

    - I tested some variants of this test (e.g. `TButton Buttons = new TButton[3]`, working with `calloc` function and others), but all of them points to the issue that `TButton` does not have a constructor without arguments, i.e., `TButton()`, but only `TButton (TComponent *AOwner)`, `TButton(void *ParentWindow)` and `TButton(const TButton &)`;
    - Any way to use operator `new` with arguments for `TButton` constructor prototypes, for an array?
- Test 2

  - Description: Creating a vector
  - Code: Also add `#include "vector.h"` on unit header...

    ```
    vector<TButton> Buttons;
    Buttons[0].Caption="it is ok";
    Buttons[1].Caption="mayday, mayday";
    ```
  - Result: Debugger exception on 3rd line:

    ```
    > Project Project1.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation
    > with message 'Acceess violation at address 401075B9 in module
    > 'vcl60.bpl'. Read of address 00000254'. Proccess stopped. Use
    > Step or Run to continue.
    ```
  - Comments:

    - Yeah, I expected that it would be raised, but I put it here to someone say how to allocate memory for more elements on that vector after created, since `vector<TButton> Buttons(3);` does not work for the same reason test1 failed :(

### General question

How to do it for any visual component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your attempts failed for the same reason - you are trying to create an array/vector of actual `TButton` object instances instead of an array/vector of **pointers** to `TButton` instances.

To create a fixed-length array of button **pointers**:

```
TButton* Buttons[3];
...
Buttons[0] = Button1;
Buttons[1] = Button2;
Buttons[2] = Button3;
...
for(index = 0; index < 3; ++index)
{
    TButton *Btn = Buttons[index];
    // use Btn as needed...
}
```

To create a dynamic-length array of button **pointers**:

```
TButton** Buttons;
...
Buttons = new TButton*[3];
Buttons[0] = Button1;
Buttons[1] = Button2;
Buttons[2] = Button3;
...
for(index = 0; index < 3; ++index)
{
    TButton *Btn = Buttons[index];
    // use Btn as needed...
}
...
delete[] Buttons;
```

To create a vector of button **pointers**:

```
std::vector<TButton*> Buttons;
...
Buttons.push_back(Button1);
Buttons.push_back(Button2);
Buttons.push_back(Button3);
...
for(index = 0; index < 3; ++index)
{
    TButton *Btn = Buttons[index];
    // use Btn as needed...
}
/*
Or:
for(std::vector<TButton*>::iterator iter = Buttons.begin(); iter != Buttons.end(); ++iter)
{
    TButton *Btn = *iter;
    // use Btn as needed...
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

All this is very nice and correctly true. But I mean the user’s question was some other intention. If for all the buttons we get each of them index does no special benefit - this is only a true method: the aim is to control all components with a click (button, panels, shapes and so on…) and don’t write for each index a new code,
That why I changed a few program’s code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)

{

typedef TPanel* TPanels;

TPanels Panels[3] = {Panel1, Panel2, Panel3};

int count;

for(count=0;count<3;count++)

Panels[count]->Left=random(100);

}
```

As one can see instead of `index` here is `count`. Certainly don’t forget insert `randomize()` to `TForm1`

Answer (score 0):

### Miraculous Typedef + Pseudo Array = Solution

- Miraculous Typedef:

  - After hours searching a way, I saw a `typedef` on that Stack Overflow and Google search journey and thought why not to:

    ```
    typedef TButton* TButtons;
    ```
  - Well, it changes all the things, because I could perform:

    ```
    TButtons Buttons[3];
    ```
- Pseudo Array:

  - The issue remained on how to allocate memory for data stored on that `Buttons[3]` array, but with knowledge of 2nd paragraph of Purpose section of my question, I thought: forget new data, data is there, point to there (so I call that to build a pseudo array, because I create only an array of pointers to existing data):

    ```
    TButtons Buttons[3] = {Button1, Button2, Button3};
    ```
  - Where `Button1`, `Button2` and `Button3` were already created when I put them on the form normally (through my mouse).

### Working example

1. Create a new vcl/forms application project;
2. Put 3 buttons as those on the left on figure bellow (`Button1`, `Button2`, `Button3`) to demonstrate that solution, and 1 great button (`Button4`) also as figure bellow to do the actions;
   [image: the figure bellow point 2]
3. Insert following code on click event of the fourth button, the great one (`Button4`);

   ```
   typedef TButton* TButtons;
   TButtons Buttons[3] = {Button1, Button2, Button3};
   int index;

   for(index=0;index<3;index++)
   {
           Buttons[index]->Caption=(AnsiString)"teste "+index+" - "+(1+random(100));
           Buttons[index]->Left=25+4*random(100);
           Buttons[index]->Top=25+4*random(100);
   }
   ```
4. Perform a "shazam!" run and play with that...
   [image: like a game project]

Comment: You don't need the `TButtons` typedef, whose name is misleading anyway since you are creating an array of individual button pointers, not an array of button lists: `TButton* Buttons[3];`.  As for the `vector` AV, that is because you did not put anything in the `vector` before accessing its elements. You have to `push_back()` the pointers into the `vector` before you can then use the `[]` operator to access them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I thought I tried `TButton* Buttons[3];` before, but I saw that I didn't... So assign addresses to that array elements complete it and brings a clear solution. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey, @RemyLebeau, answer my question with your clean quite obvious :) solution and then I assign you the correct answer (to you earn some SO points).

Comment: About your suggestion to use `push_back()`, I tried too, but the same error message about `TButton` may be created with `new` operator appeared... I had no success to create new entities, only to use addresses from existing ones... I think if I create a new class based on TButton with a constructor without arguments would solve that, but I haven't tried it yet...

Comment: There is no need to create a new class. Simply pass `NULL` to the existing `TButton` constructor if you do not want the new button object to have an Owner assigned (an Owner will free the new object for you when the Owner itself is freed).