# unique_ptr<TStringList []> dsts(new TStringList[5]) fail

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, unique-ptr, tstringlist

MyEnvironment:

```
C++ Builder XE4
```

I am trying to use array of `TStringList` using `unique_ptr<>`.

Following didn't give any error:

```
unique_ptr<int []> vals(new int [10]);
```

On the other hand, following shows error:

```
unique_ptr<TStringList []> sls(new TStringList [10]);
```

The error is 'access violation at 0x000000000: read of address 0x0000000'.

For `TStringList`, can't I use array of `unique_ptr<>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a `unique_ptr` issue: your attempt fails because you are trying to create an array of actual `TStringList` object instances instead of an array of pointers to `TStringList` instances (for further details you can take a look at [How to create an array of buttons on Borland C++ Builder and work with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12325918/3235496) and [Quality Central report #78902](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78902)).

E.g. You'll get an access violation even if you try:

```
TStringList *sls(new TStringList[10]);
```

(pointer to a dynamic array of size `10` and type `TStringList`).

You have to manage a pointer to a dynamic array of type `TStringList *`. Using `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr< std::unique_ptr<TStringList> [] > sls(
    new std::unique_ptr<TStringList>[10]);

sls[0].reset(new TStringList);
sls[1].reset(new TStringList);

sls[0]->Add("Test 00");
sls[0]->Add("Test 01");
sls[1]->Add("Test 10");
sls[1]->Add("Test 11");

ShowMessage(sls[0]->Text);
ShowMessage(sls[1]->Text);
```

Anyway, if the size is known at compile time, this is a better choice:

```
boost::array<std::unique_ptr<TStringList>, 10> sls;
```

(also take a look at [Is there any use for unique_ptr with array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16711697/3235496))

Comment: `new T[]` does create objects on the heap.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You're right, the answer contained an inaccuracy (now fixed). Thank you!